# Adorner inside ItemsControl

Tags: wpf, canvas, mvvm, itemscontrol, adorner

I am using Canvas inside ItemsControl where shapes such as rectangle, circle can be drawn. I want to resize and move the drawn shapes. I tried using adorners, but didnt find a way to use adorners inside ItemsControl, is this possible?

```
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <zc:ZoomableCanvas Loaded="Canvas_Loaded"
                                    RealizationLimit="1000" 
                                    RealizationRate="10"
                                    RealizationPriority="Background"
                                    ApplyTransform="False"
                                    Scale="{Binding ZoomableCanvas.Scale}"
                                    Offset="{Binding ZoomableCanvas.Offset}" ClipToBounds="True"
                                    Width="{Binding ZoomableCanvas.ActualWidth}"
                                    Height="{Binding ZoomableCanvas.ActualHeight}"
                                    >
                        </zc:ZoomableCanvas>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be that the answer comes a bit late, but nevertheless I write it for future reference.

The `Canvas` you are using can only show adorners if it lives within an `AdornerDecorator`. Try this:

```
<AdornerDecorator>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <zc:ZoomableCanvas Loaded="Canvas_Loaded"
                               RealizationLimit="1000" 
                               RealizationRate="10"
                               RealizationPriority="Background"
                               ApplyTransform="False"
                               Scale="{Binding ZoomableCanvas.Scale}"
                               Offset="{Binding ZoomableCanvas.Offset}" 
                               ClipToBounds="True"
                               Width="{Binding ZoomableCanvas.ActualWidth}"
                               Height="{Binding ZoomableCanvas.ActualHeight}"
                               >
            </zc:ZoomableCanvas>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</AdornerDecorator>
```

I hope this helps!